# ReactNative Flatlist - RenderItem not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, undefined, react-native-flatlist

So I'm trying to use React Native's FlatList renderItem property, but something very strange is happening.

The `data` property is set to an array which has elements which are not undefined, but then, in the `renderItem` function, it gives me an error saying that the argument of the function is undefined, unless I call the argument `item`.

Here's my code:

```
export default class Profile extends React.Component {
    onLearnMore = (user) => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('UserDetail', user)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <List>
                <FlatList
                    data={data.users}
                    renderItem={( {item} ) => {
                        console.log(item)
                        return (<ListItem
                            roundAvatar
                            title={`${item.fName} ${item.lName}`}
                            onPress={() => this.onLearnMore(item)}
                        />)
                    }}
                />
            </List>
        )
    }
}
```

If I swapped `{item}` with `{userData}`, then `userData` would be undefined later in the function. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting. Then also how does the data.users array; it should have 'key': 'value' pair objects

Comment: Where are you setting ```data```? Does the ```console.log``` output anything?

Comment: Data is just an array of JSON objects, console.logging won't do anything useful: if I log data I get what I expect, if I log item I get what I expect, but if I change the variable name to user I get undefined

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Reason is that, every object in the `data` array is referenced through `item` property of the actual parameter passed to `renderItem` function. Here, you are using [object destructuring](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/destructuring-nested-objects-9dabdd01a3b8) to extract only `item` property of the passed in object, thats why u are using `{item}`. When you are changing this name to `userData` (which is missing in the function argument), you are getting `undefined`. Have a look at the function signature of `renderItem` [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#renderitem).

If you want to use `userData` instead of `item`, then you can rename `item` to `userData` as

```
renderItem= ({item: userData}) => {...}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: This really helped me..i have wasted couple of hours wondering why flatlists weren't rendering only to realize i was using wrong variable in the destructuring part. Thanks alot

Comment: @Prasun, where in the documentation does explain this destructuring and naming requirements?  Not a cheeky comment; I am trying to learn how to read the docs and am not understanding or recognizing where these requirements are stated.

Answer (score 9):

Please read this answer carefully. I experienced it and wasted many hours to figure out why it was not re-rendering:

We need to set `extraData` prop of `FlatList` if there is any change in the state like so:

```
<FlatList data={this.state.data} extraData={this.state} .../>
```

Please see the official documentation here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Answer (score 2):

```
   renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                return (
              <Text>{item.fName + item.lName}</Text>
                );
              }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a  curlybraces { } around the item.
After adding them , now it work fine.

```
renderItem= {({item}) => this.Item(item.title)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I solve This By doing this
My code was like this =

```
setData(response)
```

so I turn it To This

```
setData([response])
```

and its works fine

Answer (score 0):

A very careless mistake which any of us might be doing :

I misspelled renderItems. The prop name is **renderItem**

```
<FlatList
      data={myData}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      renderItem={({item}) => <View></View>}
 />
```

I am surprised that react-native didn't point out to me that renderItems is not a valid prop name or any warning related to this. Anyways!