# React Native's FlatList prop renderItem requires extra "item" (item) => {item.item.name}?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here I am trying to display an array called "posts" in a FlatList.

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.posts);
    return (
        <View style={this.styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.posts}
                renderItem={(item) => <Text> {item.name} </Text>}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

As seen in this console log, the posts array is correctly populated.
[image]

But the above code doesn't display any data in the FlatList.

[image]

However, in renderItem, if I add an extra "item" property it works.

[image]

```
renderItem={(item) => <Text> {item.item.name} </Text>}
```

What is the reason for this behavior.

Comment: You might find this link helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965635/reactnative-flatlist-renderitem-not-working/48994584#48994584

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input of ReactNative's FlatList is not `item`, but an object containing 3 parameters: `item` for actual data, `index` for index and `separators` object to customize your item component. What you did is naming that object `item`, and get actual `item` from the object.

To avoid confusion, consider using ES6 shorthand:

`renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Text> {item.name} </Text>}`

Comment: Thank you for explaining :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common behavior. You can get required behavior by doing object destructuring as:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.posts}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text> {item.name} </Text>}
/>
```

If you are rendering complex component, then you might want to do like this for sake of readability of the code however.

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.posts}
    renderItem={this.renderItem} />

renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    )
}
```

Might wanna look into your question here though.

[ReactNative Flatlist - RenderItem not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965635/reactnative-flatlist-renderitem-not-working/48994584#48994584)