# Flat list is not rendering data

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am fairly new to React native. I am trying to use a Flat list, however, the list items does not display even though it shows the correct noumber of rows. Please check the image [image: List with empty rows]

This is basically the code I have put forward

```
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList} from 'react-native'
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        listItem:[
            {key: 'Insert'},
            {key: 'View'},
            {key: 'Update'},
            {key: 'Delete'}
        ]
    }

}

render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Welcome Mr. {this.props.navigation.state.params.data
                ?this.props.navigation.state.params.data:"No data passed"}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.content}>
                    <FlatList
                    data ={this.state.listItem}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                    renderItem = {(item)=>
                    <Text style={styles.item}
                    onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.key)}>{item.key}</Text>}
                    />
                </View>

            </View>
        )
    }
```

What is that I am missing?

Comment: Pay attention to that `renderItem` in FlatList: try `({ item }) => ...`instead of `(item) => ...`

Comment: @Milore - thanks a lot. It worked. Please could you explain or share some link where i could read about it.

Comment: Well, the parameter that the `renderItem` function turns you back needs to be destructured. It means that it contains a prop called `item` (and two others: index and separators I think) and it's not a generic parameter which YOU chose to call `item`. I'm not the best person to argue about that, but you can check the relative [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) and take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53776507/7581249)

Comment: @Milore plz add your answer so it can help others.

Comment: As @B.Mohammad suggested I've provided an answer, so that it can more easily help others once they arrive here. Can you check it? Thanks, happy coding :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter that the `renderItem` functional prop turns you back needs to be destructured. It means that it contains a prop called `item` (and two others: `index` and `separators`) and it's not a generic parameter which YOU chose to call `item`.

So, in order to fix your problem, you can simply replace

`renderItem = {(item)=>...`

with

`renderItem = {({ item })=>...`.

For a detailed explanation of `FlatList` and its `renderItem` prop, please take a look at the official RN [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem).