# Rendering FlatList inside TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have followed this [example](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=createMaterialTopTabNavigator%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Ftab-based-navigation-minimal.js) and tried to put a FlatList in one of the Tabs, but I can't get it to display.

So, this is my modification on the code :

```
..
    const datos=[{"codoc": 1}, {"codoc": 2}, {"codoc": 3}];
    function HomeScreen() {
      return (
          <FlatList
            data={datos}
            renderItem={(item)=>{return <View style={{flex:1}}><Text>{item.codoc}</Text></View>}}
            keyExtractor={item=>item.codoc.toString()}
          />
      );
    }
.
.
.
```

I will thank any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do **item.item.codoc** in the **renderItem**.

More information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776318/react-natives-flatlist-prop-renderitem-requires-extra-item-item-item-it)

**Edit**

I use this code.

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
 
const HomeTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Test} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Test} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

```js
const datos=[
    { "codoc": 4 },
    { "codoc": 2 },
    { "codoc": 3 }
];

function Test() {


    return (
            <FlatList
            data={datos}
            renderItem={(item)=>{
                return (
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <Text>{item.item.codoc}</Text>
                </View>)
            }}
            keyExtractor={item=>item.codoc.toString()}
          />
    );
}
```

Screen result

[image: Result]

Comment: It's ok.. but not resolve my problem... i mean, the FlatList is not showing in the Tab ..

Comment: I give you the code I used for the test. Do you want the flatlist to be displayed in the button ?

Comment: oh no .. I don't want to show the flat list in the tab button; I appreciate your help, I have corrected my problem with your help, thank you very much ..!